# How to Pass Order Details to the paypal express checkout in magento?

Tags: magento, paypal, express, checkout

I am new to magento.i wanted order details to be shown on the paypal express checkout page on the left hand side of the order summary.currently only product name is saving.

please can any one tell how can i get products other details like like price or total in magento.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Almost exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375258/how-to-pass-order-details-to-the-paypal-express-checkout-in-magento. Can't vote to close because no upvoted answers but I suspect it was a duplicate account reposting questions so downvoted

Answer (score -1):

Read the [Express Checkout Integration Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/).
To display the product information, you would need to specify the **Payment Details Item Type Fields** e.g. 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAMEm,   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_DESCm,
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMTm,   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_QTYm,  etc