# How to Pass Order Details to the paypal-express-checkout in magento?

Tags: magento, paypal, express-checkout

I am new to magento. I wanted order details to be shown on the paypal express checkout page on the left hand side of the order summary.currently only product name is saving.

How can I get products other details like price or total in magento?

Comment: I am also facing same issue on Magento 1.6.2.0 Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Express Checkout Integration Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/).
To display the product information, you would need to specify the **Payment Details Item Type Fields** e.g. 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAMEm,   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_DESCm,
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMTm,   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_QTYm,  etc